# Phusion Passenger: `Unexpected end-of-file detected.`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to get my Rails 3.2.8 app running on justhost.com's web hosting platform and I'm having a few problems. The app works fine on WEBrick when I ssh into the server and run `rails server`, but passenger (the server platform provided by justhost) is having some issues:

[image: An error message that I'm really starting to hate.]

I don't understand what this error means or have any idea on how to fix it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

In case this information is relevant, here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /home3/webgemla/rails_apps/WebGemLabs/

SetEnv GEM_HOME /home3/webgemla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

*Note: The live version of my app is at [webgemlabs.com](http://www.webgemlabs.com)*

Comment: I've got the same exact issue while trying to get my app running on my Bluehost account. Finally got Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2 up and running and installed all gems, but now getting this. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @robertmiles3 Nope, not yet. While searching for a solution I did find a few discussions where people had the same error. Their solutions didn't help me though. Here's an old thread from 3 years ago where someone had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429708/passenger-error-the-application-spawner-server-exited-unexpectedly-unexpected

It seems this error message can be triggered by a lot of things...

Comment: Please let me know if you do find a solution. I've been really busy lately and haven't had much time to look into the problem, but I really do want to get webgemlabs working... ;)

Comment: Well, I finally dove into the error log and found that my error is "mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02". So, it seems that even though I have my own Ruby/Rails/Passenger installed on my user, it's picking up the system Passenger which is set to pick up the system Ruby install of 1.8.7. I've got a ticket out with Bluehost, but so far they've been giving me an "oh well" kind of response.

Comment: @robertmiles3 Yeah, my web host isn't being very helpful either: `The type of support which you are requesting is more in depth with designing and developing your site than we are able to provide.`

I'm starting to see why a lot of developers prefer solutions like Heroku.

Comment: For the record, my final solution to the problem was to just move my app to Heroku. It took me about five minutes to get it working there, whereas I'd spent hours trying to resolve the problem here with no success.

Comment: I finally hounded Bluehost enough to get me on one of their newer servers that had a more updated version of Ruby. They finally gave in and migrated my account to one of their shared hosting servers that has Ruby 1.9.2. After that, it took me about 5 minutes to get it working. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

When I visited your link I got this error message:

```
Error message:
no such file to load -- bundler
```

You probably just need to `gem install bundler` on your server.

Comment: I've already solved that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253724/phusion-passenger-no-such-file-to-load-bundler

(Sorry if you saw that on the live app, I was just mucking with some other stuff in an attempt to solve the problem.)